# PostgreSQL how to concat interval value '2 days'

Tags: postgresql, datetime, intervals

In PostgreSQL I want to concat the `current_timestamp` with an `interval` as follows:

```
select current_timestamp + interval 2||' days'
```

But when I do, I get an error:

```
[Err] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "2"
LINE 1: select current_timestamp + interval 2||' days'
```

But if I do it like this, it works correctly:

```
select current_timestamp + interval '2 days'
```

Why does one work, but not the other?

With reference to the following page
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: Are you **really** using 8.0? (your link to the manul uses that version)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Part of the problem is that the standard SQL expression for intervals quotes the number, but not the keywords. So you have to be careful.

```
select current_date, current_date + interval '2' day;
--
2012-02-21   2012-02-23 00:00:00
```

In PostgreSQL, quoting like '2 day' and '2 days' also works.  So you might think that '2' || ' days' would be equivalent, but it's not.

```
select current_date, current_date + interval '2' || ' days';
--
2012-02-21   2012-02-21 00:00:02 days
```

The solution, as A.H. said, is to cast the result string as an interval.

You can also use a variable in place of 2.  This generates a calendar for 2012.

```
-- 0 to 365 is 366 days; 2012 is a leap year.
select ('2012-01-01'::date + (n || ' days')::interval)::date calendar_date
from generate_series(0, 365) n;
```

I use that final cast to date, because date + interval returns a timestamp.

Answer (score 38):

Please try this syntax:

```
select current_timestamp + ( 2 || ' days')::interval;
```

or even this one:

```
select current_timestamp + 2 * interval '1 day';
```

Answer (score 6):

I use this

```
SELECT now() + (Var1 || ' ' || Var2)::interval
```

no concact function