# How to set query parameters with single quotes

Tags: java, spring, oracle11g, spring-data-jpa

I'm using a oracle database.I need to run a update query through jpa repository.This is the query I have tried to execute.

```
            @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
            @Modifying
            @Query(
                value = "UPDATE transactionlog SET transactionstatus= :ps,startedat = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, readytoprocessat= (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP+ interval ':to' second)  WHERE logid IN (:li) ",
                nativeQuery = true)
            public Integer reserve(@Param("ps") short processingStatus, @Param("li") List<Integer> logIdList, @Param("to") int timeOut);
```

But this exception

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter with that name [to] did not exist; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that name [to] did not exist
```

But if i change this method as follows, it works fine.

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
            @Modifying
            @Query(
                value = "UPDATE transactionlog SET transactionstatus= :ps,startedat = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, readytoprocessat= (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP+ interval '5' second)  WHERE logid IN (:li) ",
                nativeQuery = true)
            public Integer reserve(@Param("ps") short processingStatus, @Param("li") List<Integer> logIdList);
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

Parameter with name `[to]` doesn't exist because you put `:to` between single quotes. Use `:to` instead of `':to'`.

That being said, this will not work anyway. I faced really similar issue and after some hours finally found a solution which I present [in answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42788680/3739215). For some reason, when `interval` comes into play injection of parameters doesn't work as you would expect.

Considering conclusion from the link above - I believe this should work:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
@Modifying
@Query(value = "UPDATE transactionlog SET transactionstatus= :ps,
       startedat = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
       readytoprocessat= (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + (( :to ) || 'second')\\:\\:interval)
       WHERE logid IN (:li) ",nativeQuery = true)
public Integer reserve(@Param("ps") short processingStatus, @Param("li") List<Integer> logIdList, @Param("to") int timeOut);
```

Comment: goddam spring. Mine worked without the double backslashes `\\` on interval.

Answer (score 0):

replace the :ps and all other parameter with ?1, ?2, ... and make the methos parameter match SQL parameter (the order will be important) .

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer for this problem.

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
        @Modifying
        @Query(
            value = "UPDATE transactionlog SET transactionstatus= :ps,startedat = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, readytoprocessat= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP+ NUMTODSINTERVAL( :to, 'SECOND' )  WHERE logid IN (:li) ",
            nativeQuery = true)
        public Integer reserve(@Param("ps") short processingStatus, @Param("li") List<Integer> logIdList, @Param("to") int timeOut);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
readytoprocessat= (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP+ interval ':to' second)
```

This clause is having issue, try to perform it one line prior, separately. Then you would be able to see the problem yourself.