# Spring Data/Spring JPA: How to handle named parameters when query has single quotes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm writing a Spring Data Repository to query a PostGIS spatial database.  Here's my named native query in the Entity class "MarketArea":

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "MarketArea.findByLatLng",
   query = "SELECT p FROM MarketArea p WHERE " +
           " ST_Within(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(:longitude :latitude)', 4326), the_geom))",
   resultClass = MarketArea.class)
```

And here's my query method in the Repository:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true)
Optional<MarketArea> findByLatLng(@Param("latitude") Double latitude, @Param("longitude") Double longitude);
```

When I run this, I get this error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter with that position [1] did not exist; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that position [1] did not exist
```

I think it might be related to the single quotes embedded in the query, because when I remove the quotes, it seems that the query does get closer to the database:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could
not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extractResultSet 
... 
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$2"
```

Do I need to do something to escape single quotes?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30342298/1743880) is somehow related.

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144235/jpa-hibernate-native-queries-do-not-recognize-parameters??