# Spring Data JPA Native Query - Named parameters are not being registered

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have the following repository class backed by a postgres database with the postgis extension installed.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ForumRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<ForumEntity, Long> {


  @Query(value = "SELECT *"
      + "  FROM forums"
      + "  WHERE ST_DWithin(location, 'POINT(:lon :lat)', :meters,true)"
      + "  ORDER BY ST_Distance(location, 'POINT(:lon  :lat)') ASC",
      countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM forums WHERE ST_DWithin(location, 'POINT(:lon :lat)', :meters,true)",
      nativeQuery = true)
  List<ForumEntity> findInRadius(@Param("lat") Double lat,@Param("lon") Double lon,@Param("meters") Double meters, Pageable pageable);

}
```

This Spring Data JPA repository contains one method definition which queries the database to find all forums within a certain radius. I am using named params with a native query combined with postgis's `ST_DWithin` method to perform this query.

Spring Boot starts up fine without complaint and reports that the application has started successfully. However when I try to call that query I get the following exception - `Parameter with that name [lat] did not exist; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that name [lat] did not exist`

I have tried switching over to positioned parameters, but got the same error that the parameter does not exist.

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.4

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single quotes around your parameters is probably the issue. Have a look at this  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30342298/how-to-set-query-parameters-with-single-quotes).