# Postgres Interval not working with native spring data JPA query

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I have created a native query with interval. The query works fine when i hard code `day` in query:

```
@Query(value="select * from orders where created_date  < clock_timestamp() - interval ' 5 days'",nativeQuery=true)
```

But when i provide data with `@Param` like this:

```
@Query(value="select * from orders where created_date  < clock_timestamp() - interval :day 'days'",nativeQuery=true)
List<Order> getData(@Param("day") String day)
```

I got this error:

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at
>   or near "$1"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't provide a value for an interval like that. You need to multiple the parameter value with your interval base unit:

```
"select * from orders 
where created_date  < clock_timestamp() - (interval '1' day) * :days"
```

As you are dealing with days, you can simplify that to:

```
"select * from orders 
where created_date  < clock_timestamp() - :days"
```

Another option is the [`make_interval()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#id-1.5.8.14.5.2.2.22.1.1) function. You can pass multiple parameters for different units.

```
"select * from orders 
where created_date  < clock_timestamp() - make_interval(days => :days)"
```

The notation `days => ...` is a named parameter for a function call. If the variable represents hours, you could use `make_interval(hours => ..)`

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: what about `interval '2 hour'`... ?

Comment: You mean `(interval '1' hour) * :hours` ?

Comment: I tried the `(interval '1 hour') * :hours`, but my results are incorrect, although there is no exception anymore. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57795441/postgres-interval-spring-data-dynamic-parameter-not-working

Comment: Nice, and works in a Query annotation, but does not work in a Formula annotation. There, I ended up having `make_interval(0,0,0,1)` to specify a 1-day interval.

Comment: @Philippe answer is the correct way to do it. Much cleaner to pass simple ints.

Comment: `ERROR: function make_interval(days => character varying) does not exist`

Comment: You need to pass numbers, not strings

Answer (score 6):

One solution is provided in this entry [Spring Boot Query annotation with nativeQuery doesn't work in Postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28955273/spring-boot-query-annotation-with-nativequery-doesnt-work-in-postgresql)

Basically:

```
@Query(value="select * from orders where created_date  < clock_timestamp() - ( :toTime )\\:\\:interval",nativeQuery=true)
```

'toTime' is a Param from your repository and could be days, hour, minute... etc(review interval doc in Postgres) @Param("toTime") String toTime

Comment: This is what solved my issue - escaping the double colons since JPA was interpreting that as substitution variables

Comment: This works in a Query annotation but does not work in a Formula annotation. In the Formula annotation, I ended up writing it as `make_interval(0,0,0,1)` to specify a 1 day interval.

Comment: @sergio could you please tell me how i can pass my sql correctly in the query annotation :  DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE my_column <  (NOW() - INTERVAL '30 minutes') and i want to pass '30 minutes' as a param in my java method