# Postgres Interval Spring Data Dynamic Parameter not working

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I need to pass in a dynamic param to a Spring Data Postgres Native Query. The param is in an interval expression.

At the time of running the code, I verify from pgAdmin that the following returns **1 result only (correctly):**

`select * from recalls_t where created_date <=  (now() - interval '18 hour')`

**PROBLEM:**

1) In the Spring Data code, the following `?1` notation returns **2 results incorrectly**:

```
@Query(value="select * from recalls_t where created_date <=  (now() - interval '?1 hour')", 
       nativeQuery=true)
public List<RecallsT> findActiveRecallsInLastHrs(@Param("hours") int hours);
```

2) Then I tried the solution in this thread: [Postgres Interval not working with native spring data JPA query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43767284/postgres-interval-not-working-with-native-spring-data-jpa-query)

They said to use a multiple of a single-unit interval. But this also returns **2 results incorrectly**:

```
@Query(value="select * from recalls_t where created_date <=  (now() - 
       (interval '1 hour') * :hours)", 
       nativeQuery=true)
public List<RecallsT> findActiveRecallsInLastHrs(@Param("hours") int hours);
```

The only way I found to fix this is to hard-code the number "18" in my Spring Data query. So now there's no dynamic param, and I get 1 result correctly. None of the Dynamic Param implementations work.

Comment: `interval '1 hour) * :hours'` should be `interval '1 hour') * :hours` (note the single quotes around `'1 hour'`

Comment: Yes that's what I tried. Sorry for the typo, I corrected it in my post. I tried `(interval '1 hour') * :hours` and the result were incorrect (although there was no exception). I think there's a bug somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

Try by passing a String ?

```
@Query(value="select * from recalls_t where created_date <=  (now() - interval ?1)", 
       nativeQuery=true)
public List<RecallsT> findActiveRecallsInLastHrs(String interval);

// ... 

findActiveRecallsInLastHrs("1 hour");
```