# Spring, Hibernate : Check for timestamp within expiration time

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hql

I am working on a Spring-MVC project with Hibernate and DB as Postgres in which there is a possibility to assign tasks to individual people who are part of a group.

Now the tasks have end-time, and I have a scheduler running which every 30 minutes would check if task has around 48hours remaining to finish, if that's the case, then I would send an email.

Unfortunately, I cannot just check for less than 48 hours, as I am also checking for less then 12 hours and less then 8hours.

So, I thought why not to check that the time remaining is between 47-48hours. And I don't know how to check such a condition.

So, basically, from the current time, if the row has a timestamp which is 47-48hours far away, I want to retrieve that row. 
I know how to check for more then what is now, and below is the code. Can anyone help me how to check within 47-48hours. Thanks a lot.

Code :

```
   @Override
       public List<GroupNotes> findGroupNotesWithExpiryInFortyEightHours() {
            int val = 0;
            Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
            Query query = session.createQuery("from GroupNotes as gn where gn.zugwisenPersonId!=:val and gn.timeToend>:timestamp");

        }
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which database are you using and can you allowed to do it in CreateSqlCreteria I mean with sql not with HQL

Comment: @erhun : I can use SQL queries as well, I am using Postgres.

Comment: You can check interval usage  in Postgresql in  that SO questions there is some http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376350/postgresql-how-to-concat-interval-value-2-days

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query should do the job (it was not tested it though, I do not have an IDE here):

```
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long plus47Hours = currentTime + (47 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
Timestamp plus47HoursTS = new Timestamp(plus47Hours);

long plus48Hours = currentTime + (48 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
Timestamp plus48HoursTS = new Timestamp(plus48Hours);

Query query = session.createQuery("from GroupNotes as gn where gn.zugwisenPersonId!=:val and gn.timeToend > :from and gn.timeToend < :to");
query.setParameter("from", plus47HoursTS);
query.setParameter("to", plus48HoursTS);
```