# interpolate column into postgres interval

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Postgresql table I'm using to store information about scheduled processes, including the last time a process was executed. Different processes have different requirements about how often they run.

I pull a list of processes I need to re-run like this:

```
SELECT * FROM processes WHERE last_run < now() - interval '2 hours'
```

I've added a new column called `exec_interval` that has a value in minutes of how often the task should run so I can do away with the hard-coded value.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM processes WHERE last_run < now() - interval exec_interval || ' minutes'
```

But that throws a syntax error. Is there an accepted way to handle this scenario?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376350/postgresql-how-to-concat-interval-value-2-days

Comment: `SELECT * FROM processes WHERE last_run < now() - (exec_interval||' minute')::interval`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest way to do this is probably:

```
SELECT 
     * 
FROM 
    processes 
WHERE 
    last_run < now() - exec_interval * interval '1 minute' ;
```

Or, probably better:

```
SELECT 
     * 
FROM 
    processes 
WHERE 
    last_run + exec_interval * interval '1 minute' < now() ;
```

(that is, you keep everything that can be computed from one row of te table on just one side of the `<`, instead of having columns (or f(columns)) in *both* sides)

... together with the following (functional) index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_next_run 
    ON processes ( (last_run + (exec_interval * interval '1 minutes') ) ) ;
```

which will allow for a nice execution plan such as:

```
| QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                     |
| :----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| Bitmap Heap Scan on processes  (cost=1060.05..2799.58 rows=49001 width=16) (actual time=10.007..19.612 rows=49792 loops=1)     |
|   Recheck Cond: ((last_run + ((exec_interval)::double precision * '00:01:00'::interval)) < now())                              |
|   Heap Blocks: exact=637                                                                                                       |
|   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_next_run  (cost=0.00..1047.80 rows=49001 width=0) (actual time=9.919..9.919 rows=49792 loops=1) |
|         Index Cond: ((last_run + ((exec_interval)::double precision * '00:01:00'::interval)) < now())                          |
| Planning time: 0.204 ms                                                                                                        |
| Execution time: 23.619 ms                                                                                                      |
```

Check all the setup and several smallish variations at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=5c7fb5d36b2eb6a899fbe5e41789bf53)*

Comment: Strange that many forget about the nice function `make_interval()`: `make_interval(mins := exec_interval)`

Comment: @Abelisto: It's nice to have, but I've always thought that  `n * interval '1 minute'` is closer to the SQL standard...