# How to wrap Jpa @Query placeholder in single quotes

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a query like so:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "" +
      "SELECT f.name AS name " +
      "FROM foo f " +
      "WHERE f.date > current_date - INTERVAL :days DAY")
Optional<Object> foo(Integer days);
```

The problem is that `:days` requires single quotes around it.

When I try doing something like this

```
"WHERE f.date > current_date - INTERVAL '" + ":days" + "' DAY"
```

or this

```
"WHERE f.date > current_date - INTERVAL ':days' DAY"
```

the `:days` placeholder does not get escaped.

I am using a Postgres database. Does anyone have a solution to this?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I just needed to do the following

```
"WHERE f.date > current_date - :days * INTERVAL '1' DAY"
```

Thanks to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9376576/8928554)